# How do I dual boot two versions of Windows 10 while hiding all other disk partitions from the 2nd win install

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, hide

GPT partitions, EFI boot.
I want to have 2 windows 10 installs, one "normal" and other as a "test". I don't want the "test" version not to be able to change or even see anything but its own partition and I guess its own boot partition. Not looking to do this with Disk Management by removing the drive letter name. I would like something a bit more betterer. Something a virus can easily get around. I tried it with grub parttool hd0,1 hidden+, but apparently grub doesn't do it with gpt partitions.

Comment: The simplest solution, use 2 disks and BitLocker.  This way the only way the other installation can mount the both disk, is if the volume is mounted, which of course requires the passphrase.

Comment: Its a laptop, I can only have 1 disk.

Comment: Bitlocker works on volumes, not disks, you should have different volumes anyway when using dual boot windows. But even with Bitlocker, a virus could just  ignore the encryption and delete the volume itself.

Comment: Looks like there are no good options for me. I guess I'll be going with a triple booting, 2 windows 10 and Ubuntu on a MBR. Installing Bitlocker on my normal drive partition Pin-Boot lock?, and having grub bootloader set that normal windows partition to hiden/system utility (flag 0x27). I wish there was a simple command that disables a partition or drive until until you reboot. Alternatively wish I had a desktop so I can hardwire a switch to kill power to one drive and give power to the other.